# How to fix WhiteScreen in Easyphp while installing Prestashop for the first time?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, easyphp

i´m new to this place and new to the hole programming stuff so please be patient. 
I started the try to install Prestashop on Easyphp Devserver for my own and had a few Problems i solved allready but for my actual Problem i didn´t find an answer on the internet.

I´m using Easyphp 16.1 and want to install Prestashop 1.6.0.5 on it. I created a database via phpmyadmin, my http server is running with php 5.6 and even my database server is running with mysql. 
Now i started the installation and it worked fine till that point when the installation should start. Everytime i start Step 6 "istallation" i get an White Screen instead of an bar that shows me the installationprocess going on. 
First i´ve been reading about an error in cause of Ressource-configurations that may be increased. I did. No Change.
Then i saw an commendation in Step 3 when my Systemcompatibility got checked from the istallguide that is (roughly) "No PDO for mysql". 
I activated it in the php.ini file and checked wheter its activated and sure it is now. But my white screen appears still everytime i try to install.

Somebody now ideas what i could do?

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Check your server error logs, it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: why don't you try Apache webserver....